# get path to current desktop wallpaper

Tags: c++, windows, desktop-wallpaper

As mentioned in the title, I want to get the path to the current desktop wallpaper (in C++). I tried to use `SystemParametersInfo` with `SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER`. But this only returns this:

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper

What I really need would be something like this:

> C:\User\...\image.png

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: For some reason each Window version handles this differently. There is no answer as far as I know. You don't really need this information anyway.

Comment: You can find this piece of information here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\TranscodedImageCache (Windows 10). And yes, I definitely need the info!

Comment: The documented interface is [IDesktopWallpaper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper). Undocumented registry keys are subject to change.

Answer (score 2):

There is registry hive **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop**. It has value with name **Wallpaper**. It contains the path to the current wallpaper.

Comment: This path also just `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper`.

Comment: I want to do stuff with the original file, so I need the path to the original file.  So basically, I want to know the path to the file which got copied into the "Transcoded Wallpaper".

Comment: May be this can be helpful. You can get current theme via [GetCurrentThemeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and parse that file. .theme file contains section Control Panel\Desktop with parameter Wallpaper

Comment: the parameter wallpaper contains the same. But the parameter TranscodedImageCache contains exactly what I am searching for! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop section of your registry and find six recent files transcoded to TranscodedWallpaper.
There names

- TranscodedImageCache
- TranscodedImageCache_000
- TranscodedImageCache_001
- TranscodedImageCache_002
- TranscodedImageCache_003
- TranscodedImageCache_004

Basically, it can be read without any tools:
[Here it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp5Bl.png)
But it can be converted to more readable view with any tool capable to show unicode text